# How to define a generic type that works as an alias in Python

Tags: python, python-typing

Not sure if the title is 100% right, but it's simpler to explain using the following example:

```py
class MyObject1:
    ...

class MyObject2:
    ...

@dataclass
class DataClass:
    source1: MyType[MyObject1]
    source2: MyType[MyObject2]
```

In this case, I'm looking for `MyType` to be something like:

```py
MyType[T] = AliasTo(Union[T, str, None])
```

I feel like it could possibly be implemented using `Generic` but I can't make my head around how to do it.

(I'm using Python 3.8)

Comment: You just use `MyType = Union[T, str, None]`, although, you might want to use the new `typing.TypeAlias` to specify this explicitly, `MyType: TypeAlias = Union[T, str, None]` which will be available in future versions (at least python 3.10) but it would be available in `typing_extensions`

Comment: What would `MyType[MyObject1]` mean here? That `source1` could be either a `MyObject1`, a `str` or `None`? So you want `MyType` to be some sort of parameterised type that means "either a `str`, `None`, or whatever type was passed"? How often would you need this to make it a good idea? Isn't defining a `MyType1` to be `Union[MyObject1, str, None]` a better idea and far more readable?

Comment: @Grismar I mean, it *is* possible and part of the spec. I agree, though, that in this case, it might be more readable to just have the explicit union

Comment: @Grismar _"So you want `MyType` to be some sort of parameterised type that means 'either a `str`, `None`, or whatever type was passed'?"_ Yes, exactly so. Answering your next question: I would need it quite often, so defining a separate type for each class type, would be hard to achieve.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Seems that `MyType = Union[T, str, None]` works. At least, PyCharm resolves this correctly. I will check how MyPy picks it up, but so far it looks like a solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an easy way to make the type definition itself parameterisable without making it a class unto itself.

But perhaps this is close enough to what you want:

```
from typing import TypeVar


class MyClass:
    pass


# instead of defining a parameterisable type, why not define the types you need?
MyType = TypeVar('MyType', MyClass, str, None)


def fun(x: MyType):
    if isinstance(x, MyClass):
        print('MyClass', x)
    elif isinstance(x, str):
        print('str', x)
    elif x is None:
        print('None')
    else:
        print('Something unexpected was passed')


fun(MyClass())
fun('test')
fun(None)
fun(1)
```

Output:

```
MyClass <__main__.MyClass object at 0x0000028D566CEA10>
str test
None
Something unexpected was passed
```

And in editors that check for it (for example in my case PyCharm), you get a warning like "Expected type 'MyType', got 'int' instead" on the last line `fun(1)`, specifically on the `1`.

Note: from the comments you've made it clear this is not ideal for you, but I'll leave the answer up for others looking and deciding it does work for them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As mentioned in the comments, I would probably be looking for a more generic solution.

Comment: You can. Just use a type alias here

Answer (score 2):

Define a `TypeVar` and a class that inherits from Union

In my example you see me inheriting from `tuple` actually,
but it is just to show that b really has inferred type `str`

```
from typing import *;

T = TypeVar("T");
class TupleAlias(tuple[T, str, None]): ...

def f(u: TupleAlias[int]):
    a, b, c = u;
    return b.capitalize();
pass
```

(in the picture, you should see completions for `str` type)

[image]

Comment: You don't need any of this, you can just use a type alias